# Does a ger (convert) say Yizkor?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, family-members, yizkor

A convert's biological parents are not their parents in a halachic sense.  In some senses the converting beis din is "responsible" for the convert in the way of parents.  In name, at least, the ger's parents are Avrohom Avinu and Sarah Imenu.  When, if ever, does a convert say yizkor?

Comment: Possibly related: [When if ever are converts still related to their relatives](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12716/when-if-ever-are-converts-still-related-to-their-relatives)  [Is a convert obliged to honor his parents](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14717/is-a-convert-obliged-to-honor-his-parents) [Can a convert mourn for their Jewish parents](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19134/can-a-convert-mourn-for-their-jewish-parents)

Comment: also related: [May or should a convert recite kaddish after his biological parents death](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3842/may-or-should-a-convert-recite-kaddish-after-his-biological-parents-deaths)

Comment: Can't I say Yizkor for whomever I want?

Comment: @DoubleAA is that the case?  I was under the impression that one said Yizkor only for a deceased relative.  Perhaps the question would be better formulated as "given the custom for one whose parents are still living, when should a ger begin to say yizkor?"

Comment: "given the custom for one whose parents are still living to leave during and refrain from saying yizkor..."

Comment: My understanding is that that custom developed in some communities out of a fear for the evil eye by Yizkor-sayers onto those present but not saying anything. It would seem mimanafshach that after his biological parents are dead there isn't anything to stop him from staying inside during Yizkor.

Comment: re your first point: If I can say a El Malei for anyone (eg a certain Rabbi, all the martyrs of the Holocaust) why can't I pray for them with the Yizkor nussach?

Comment: @DoubleAA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10568

Comment: Dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37704/is-a-convert-allowed-to-say-yizkor-for-their-non-jewish-parents

Answer (score 4):

As a convert, I've only asked the question with respect to kaddish and shiva.  I've posted the answers I've received on those questions elsewhere (in sum, my rav relying on the Rema said "no kaddish or shiva" but there are other chashuva sources who disagree; I go with my Rav).  Since my late Rav, Rabbi Gedaliah Anemer, zt'l, said "no" to those questions, it never occurred to me to ask about Yizkor.  But I do know that with respect to my Jewish-born wife, Rabbi Anemer (and his student and successor, Rabbi Dovid Rosenbaum, shlita), said she could not say Yizkor until her parent had been dead one year.  Given that I never bothered asking about Yizkor.  I don't know any converts who stay around for Yizkor, and I don't either.

Comment: What about Avraham and Sara?

Answer (score 3):

A convert should **not** say Yizkor for his\her non-Jewish parents, for the simple reason that the text of Yizkor is specific to Jews (as we ask God to bind the soul of the deceased with those of their ancestors Abraham, Isaac, Jacob, Sarah, Rebecca, Rachel and Leah.)

However, a convert **may** say a personal prayer in remembrance of his\her parents in place of the traditional Yizkor prayer.

*For practical applications, please consult your rabbi.*

Sources: http://www.shamash.org/lists/scj-faq/HTML/faq/11-06-17.html ; http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=4999 ; http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=37