# Is a convert allowed to say Yizkor for their non-Jewish parents?

Tags: death, conversion-to-judaism, children-parenting, yizkor

Is a convert allowed to say Yizkor for their deceased parents if they are non-Jewish?

Comment: similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3842

Comment: Discussion in chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15357269#15357269) about this being a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A convert should **not** say *Yizkor* for his\her non-Jewish parents, for the simple reason that the text of Yizkor is specific to Jews (as we ask God to bind the soul of the deceased with those of their ancestors Abraham, Isaac, Jacob, Sarah, Rebecca, Rachel and Leah.)

However, a convert **may** say a personal prayer in remembrance of his\her parents in place of the traditional *Yizkor* prayer.

*For practical applications, please consult your rabbi.*

Sources: http://www.shamash.org/lists/scj-faq/HTML/faq/11-06-17.html ; http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=4999 ; http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=37